# How do I get back to my spawn point?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been travelling in my world on Minecraft for iPad (version 0.10.4). I have lots of cool stuff, and I can't find my way back to my house with my stuff. So, if I die I will lose all of it, and it took me hours to find.

My house is near my spawn point. How do I find my way back there? My world is an infinite world, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Craft yourself a [compass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compass) using 4 iron ingots and 1 redstone.

A compass always points towards your spawn point (no matter if this is the world spawn or your bed)

[image: How to craft a compass]
[image: compass]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/archive/9/92/20101220103654!Compass.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Build a temporary house where you are and dig until you find red stone and iron. Then make a compass and destroy the tempory house. Follow the compass until you get back home.

Answer (score 0):

Try a compass? I'm not sure if that points to your origional spawn or your current spawn in pe but in computer it would point to your origional spawn

Comment: it points towards your spawn location. When you change your spawn location using a bed it will point towards that bed